# Method to Use a fifo Queue with background worker, and populating the queue with method(parameter)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, backgroundworker

Currently I am trying to create a background worker that can loop through some class functions, I created a class to store a few objects that are getting used globally (user settings and a few other things).

I essentially need to store the following line as an Action.

```
GV_Acc.load_page("weburl", 0);
```

Here is the majority of the code that I am using
Form Containing a Button:

```
private void btn_initialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    CusWorker worker = new CusWorker();
    worker.addwork(GV_Acc.load_page("weburl", 0));
    worker.addwork(GV_Acc.json_populate(0));
    worker.asyncworker.RunWorkerAsync();}
```

These are the 2 Classes I am using:

```
public class CusWorker
{
    public BackgroundQueue asyncqueue { get;private set; }
    private int tasks;
    public System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker asyncworker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    public CusWorker()
    {
        asyncqueue = new BackgroundQueue();
        asyncworker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(asyncworker_DoWork);
        asyncworker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(asyncworker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }
    public void addwork(Action action)
    {
        asyncqueue.QueueTask(action);
    }
    private void asyncworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void asyncworker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (asyncqueue != null)
        {
            asyncworker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class BackgroundQueue
{
    private Task previousTask = Task.FromResult(true);
    private object key = new object();
    public Task QueueTask(Action action)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            previousTask = previousTask.ContinueWith(t => action()
                , CancellationToken.None
                , TaskContinuationOptions.None
                , TaskScheduler.Default);
            return previousTask;
        }
    }
    public Task<T> QueueTask<T>(Func<T> work)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var task = previousTask.ContinueWith(t => work()
                , CancellationToken.None
                , TaskContinuationOptions.None
                , TaskScheduler.Default);
            previousTask = task;
            return task;
        }
    }
}}
```

So Should I use "Actions" Or is there a better way to do what I am attempting?

PS:Honestly I don't have any idea what the above does at this point. All I know is that when I run my program and click the button, everything locks up for about 30 seconds. I'm trying to stop that from happening but I don't know where to start now. Am I using any of the above code correctly?

Edit: Found out that when Something is added to the background Queue it starts work immediately, So I don't need the background worker. I Will have to learn more about tasks.

Comment: Use TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a work around method and getting rid of the BackgroundWorker.
Did not understand Tasks or Actions, now that I know more about the syntax, The background worker is completely useless. Correct Syntax 
    `queue = new BackgroundQueue();
    queue.queuetask(() => {code to run};);`

I did not realize that the Method starts running the moment it is passed to QueueTask().
*Feeling Pretty Stupid for this question*